# How do I use my hat?

Tags: shantae-half-genie-hero, shantae-pirate-queens-quest

After clearing Sequin Town in the "Pirate Queen's Quest" DLC for *Shantae: ½ Genie Hero* I was awarded the Pirate Hat. It is supposed to allow Risky Boots to glide, but that isn't happening. How do I use my hat to glide?

Answer (score 4):

I feel silly. I forgot to try the <kbd>R</kbd> on the Switch. So the upper right shoulder button on any version then.